# Form item disappearing when failing nested validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, cocoon-gem

I have a Rails 5 app, and I'm having a problem with validations using the Cocoon gem with nested, dynamic forms.

When a validation on my `Book` model fails, and my `create` action renders `:new`, the `Author` field disappears from my new book form.

One thing I've noticed is that when the validation fails, rather than passing `authors` back into my form, it's passing `book_authors` back because of the line `@book.book_authors.build(author_id: author.id)` in my `create` action. Pretty sure this is the cause of my issue, but don't know how to fix it.

`books_controller.rb`

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def new
    @book = Book.new
    @book.authors.build
  end

  def create
    @book = current_user.books.create(book_params)
    params[:book][:authors_attributes].each do |k,v|
      author = Author.find_or_create_by(name: v['name'], user_id: current_user.id)
      @book.book_authors.build(author_id: author.id)
    end

    if @book.save
        redirect_to book_path(@book)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title, :published_city, :description, author_ids:[])
  end

  def author_params
    params.require(:book).permit(authors_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

`book.rb`

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :book_authors
  has_many :authors, through: :book_authors
  belongs_to :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors, allow_destroy: true
  validates :title, :published_city, presence: true
  validates_associated :authors, inverse_of: :book
end
```

`book_author.rb`

```
class BookAuthor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :author
end
```

`author.rb`

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_authors
  has_many :books, through: :book_authors

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

`new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @book do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, required: true %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
  <div id='authors'>
    <%= f.fields_for :authors do |author| %>
      <%= render 'author_fields', :f => author %>
    <% end %>
    <div class='links'>
      <%= link_to_add_association 'Add another author', f, :authors %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= f.text_field :published_city %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So if I read this correctly, you do not use the standard create/save, because you first want to check if an author already exists, right? Maybe you should do this explicitly from the UI and let the user either select an existing author, and if it does not exist create a new one? Check https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/A-guide-to-doing-nested-model-forms#the-look-up-or-create-belongs_to

Comment: @nathanvda Yeah, that's correct. The problem with the solution you've linked to is that I'm pulling data in from an API and pre-populating the form, which is why I'm using the `.find_and_create_by` method. Very hard for me to handle all this from the UI...